# Making a request in Alamofire 4.0 with a custom response

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Having difficulty making a request in `Alamofire 4.0`. Previously I would use:

**Code Snippet :**

```
alamoManager.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .url, headers: nil).responseObject { (response: Response<MyCustomResponse, NSError>) in


        }
```

Where `alamoManager` is the old `Manager` object (now renamed `SessionManager`). However I can't see anything in the docs about how to pass a custom response (Conforms to Mappable). Has anybody achieved this? Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I used to type Alamofire 4.0 request like this:

```
import Alamofire

...

let parameters : Parameters = ["task":"setUser"]

Alamofire.request(url, parameters: parameters)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { response in
        //print(parameters), print(response.request), print(response.response), print(response.result)
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
            print("HTTP code @apiGetUser: \(statusCode)")

            // ...

        case .failure(let error):
            // ...
        }
}
```